# mouseJoint box2dweb doesn't work

Tags: mouse, box2dweb

I am trying to catch object with mouse using mousejoint. As I am a fool I've stolen the code. But it isnt working or me.

I am getting this errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #< ba > has no method 'IsActive' Box2dWeb-2.1.a.3.min.js:236
>   Uncaught TypeError: Object #< ba > has no method 'SetAwake' Box2dWeb-2.1.a.3.min.js:223

here is the code:

```
var def = new b2MouseJointDef();

            def.bodyA = ground;
            def.bodyB = body;
            def.target = p;

            def.collideConnected = true;
            def.maxForce = 1000 * body.GetMass();
            def.dampingRatio = 0;

            mouse_joint = world.CreateJoint(def);

            body.SetAwake(true);
```

And this is the body

```
function createBox(world, x, y, width, height, options) {
options = $.extend(true, {
    'density' : 1.0 ,
    'friction' : 1.0 ,
    'restitution' : 0.5 ,

    'linearDamping' : 0.0 ,
    'angularDamping' : 0.0 ,

    'type' : b2Body.b2_dynamicBody
}, options);

var body_def = new b2BodyDef();
var fix_def = new b2FixtureDef();

fix_def.density = options.density;
fix_def.friction = options.friction;
fix_def.restitution = options.restitution;

fix_def.shape = new b2PolygonShape();

fix_def.shape.SetAsBox( width , height );

body_def.position.Set(x , y);

body_def.linearDamping = options.linearDamping;
body_def.angularDamping = options.angularDamping;

body_def.type = options.type;
body_def.userData = options.user_data;

var b = world.CreateBody( body_def );
var f = b.CreateFixture(fix_def);

return b;
```

}

Maybe someone can help?

Falk

Answer (score 0):

I can answer half of the question:

if I set up the ground with

```
ground = createBox(world, 4, 1, 4 , 0.5, {type : b2Body.b2_staticBody});
```

instead with this function:
     var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef();

```
var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef();
fixDef.density = 1.0;
fixDef.friction = 1.0;
fixDef.restitution = 0.5;

fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;

//mention half the sizes
fixDef.shape.SetAsBox(4.00 , .5);

//set the position of the center
bodyDef.position.Set(4.10 , 1);

return world.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);
```

then it is working. But why?